# Flutter mocktail get error when put mock getx controller

Tags: flutter, mocking, flutter-getx

I have this getx controller :

```
class CustomerPOAutocompleteState extends GetxController {
  CustomerPOAutocompleteState();
...
  Future<void> getCustomer(String title, String? propertyId) async {
    var result = await RRGraphQL().artemis!...
    _customers =...
    update(['update']);
  }
```

Now by Mock `mocktail` I created a mock class:

```
class MockController extends Mock implements CustomerPOAutocompleteState {}
```

When I try to put it I got error:

```
void main() {

  late MockController mockController;
  setUpAll(() {
    mockController = MockController();
  });

...

    testWidgets('test', (WidgetTester tester) async {

      Get.put<CustomerPOAutocompleteState>(mockController,tag: "");
```

error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown running a test:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'InternalFinalCallback<void>'
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED Answer

This error occurs since `Get.put` performs calls on your `GetxController` which have not been mocked out correctly.

You can either do this manually (you will have to check the implementation details of `Get.put` and `GetxController`). Or you can do, what the Get documentation suggests and let your mock extend `GetxController` and use `Mock` as a mixin.

```dart
class MockController extends GetxController
    with Mock
    implements CustomerPOAutocompleteState {}
```

Check out this full example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class DemoController extends GetxController {
  var count = 0.obs;

  increment() => count++;
}

class MockController extends GetxController
    with Mock
    implements DemoController {}

main() {
  late MockController mockController;
  setUpAll(() {
    mockController = MockController();
  });

  test('GetX Test', () {
    when(() => mockController.count).thenAnswer((_) => 12.obs);

    Get.put<DemoController>(mockController, tag: "");
    mockController.increment();
    expect(mockController.count.value, 12);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you have a simple class, but the getx controller seems different when you want to mock it .Seems it has some property that should not be a null value .

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please note, that the error was caused by what I had said in my initial answer. The mock was lacking stubbed method calls. However, there is a section about unit testing in the Get documentation, which explains what to do.

Comment: Strange! I'm trying to do the same but it gives me compile time error and won't let me reference super class when putting the mocked subclass. Specifically the error is:
`A value of type 'DemoController' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'mockController'` Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can just copy paste the whole example into one file and hit run. You need to have all dependencies declared in the `pubspec.yaml`, though. Especially, make sure to declare MockController correctly: `class MockController extends GetxController with Mock implements DemoController {}`.